# MVC identity with database first Entity Framework Error System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using the MVC with Identity.I am using custom Identity from [here](http://www.codingfreaks.de/2014/06/16/microsoft-aspnet-identity-in-bestehender-anwendung-einsetzen-teil-2/). It's is working fine for local SQL Server 2012, but when I host the database into server and if I try to register it throws this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type MyUser is not part of the model for the current context.

```
 //Webconfig

<add name="IdentityEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.IdentityModel.csdl|res://*/DAL.IdentityModel.ssdl|res://*/DAL.IdentityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxxx;initial catalog=Identiydatabase;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";
    private MyUserManager _userManager;
    public AccountController()
    {
    }
    public AccountController(MyUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }
     public MyUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<MyUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
  [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new MyUser
            {
                Email = model.Email
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,model.Password);
  }

   //Application DBContext
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser, MyRole, long, MyLogin, MyUserRole, MyClaim>
{
    #region constructors and destructors

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("IdentityEntities")
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    { return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // Map Entities to their tables.
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        // Set AutoIncrement-Properties
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyClaim>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyRole>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        // Override some column mappings that do not match our default
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.UserName).HasColumnName("Login");
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyUser>().Property(r => r.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("Password");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post DBContext ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a proper title that represents a problem/question, not a bunch of tags.

Comment: I have Updated the code DBContext kindly suggest

Comment: What about if you delete and recreate all the entities? From time to time it has helped me or you could check if for any strange reason you have two connection strings in the web config.

Comment: but maybe it will be more coding from exist code,I dont know why that error is getting.It works fine when i use it in locally

Comment: if i use providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" in webconfig file  it works but it wont work providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this with remplace `YourServer` by server name (or IP) :

```
<add name="IdentityEntities" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=YourServer;Database=Identiydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" />
```